# Trap 'Ctrl + c' for bash script but not for process open in this script

Tags: bash, trap

I tried to have an interactive program in a bash script :

```
my_program
```

And I wish to be able to close it with 'Ctrl + c'.
But when I do it my script is closing as well.

I know about.

```
trap '' 2
my_program
trap 2
```

But in this case, I just can't close `my_program` with Ctrl + c.

Do you have any idea how to allow Ctrl + c on a program, but not closing the script running it ?

EDIT : add example

```
#!/bin/bash
my_program
my_program2
```

If i use Ctrl + c to close `my_program`, `my_program2` is never executed because the whole script is exited.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use `trap true 2` or `trap : 2` instead of `trap '' 2`. That's what "help trap" in a bash shell says about it:

> If ARG is the null string each SIGNAL_SPEC is ignored by the
>       shell **and by the commands it invokes**.

Example:

```
$ cat /tmp/test
#! /bin/sh
trap : INT
cat
echo first cat killed
cat
echo second cat killed
echo done
$ /tmp/test
   <press control-C>
^Cfirst cat killed
   <press control-C>
^Csecond cat killed
done
```

Comment: How about killing `tail`s instead of killing cats next time?

Answer (score 12):

You can reset a trap to its default by giving the trap command `-` as its action argument. If you do this in a [subshell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_12), it won't affect the trap in the parent shell.  In your script, you can do this for each command that you need to be interruptible with Ctrl-C:

```
#!/bin/bash
# make the shell (and its children) ignore SIGINT
trap '' INT
.
.
.
# but this child won't ignore SIGINT
(trap - INT; my_program)
# the rest of the script is still ignoring SIGINT
.
.
.
```

Comment: While the accepted answer is probably better and more canonical for shell, this is a great answer in itself in that it introduces the general principle (not shell-specific) for how to do this sort of signal masking/ignoring safely.

Comment: I guess you can `exec my_program` in the subshell, to be slightly more efficient.

Comment: @R.. that's absolutely not shell specific -- if you set a signal to SIG_IGN (that's what trap with an empty string is doing), that state will be inherited through exec(), except for SIGCHLD. That's POSIX mandated behavior. See also the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32708086/ignoring-signals-in-parent-process

Comment: @mosvy: I don't see what part of my comment you're disagreeing with. My whole point was that "mask/ignore before fork, unmask/unignore in the child before exec" is a general principle that's useful to know outside the context of just shell programming.

Comment: @TobySpeight: Yes, `exec` would be preferable too.

Comment: This is a very useful answer. As an experienced Linux user, I can say I've never heard of this before. It has quite a lot of uses... you got my upvote and my bookmark.

Answer (score -1):

When you use <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, you *interrupt* the program ("**kill**" it).
What you are probably looking for is to *suspend* your program ("**pause**" it). For this, you can use <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.
Once your program is paused, you can see it using `jobs`. For example:
`[1]+  Stopped    ./foobar`
Here I only have one job, job #1, but there can be more than one - each job has its own number.
You can control you suspended process using a number of commands, for example `bg`, `fg` and `kill`.
`bg %1` will restart job #1 in the **b**ack**g**round
`fg %1` will restart job #1 in the **f**ore**g**round
`kill %1` will kill job #1
Note that you can use `bg` and `fg` with no arguments if you only have one active job.

Comment: Thank you but no, I wish to do Ctrl + c.